# Audio Recording in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, audio-recording

I am trying to record audio with ReactJS and want to store in my node server.

For it I try to use "react-audio-recorder" module, but I am getting some issues in it like while recording audios continuously one after another, module is getting failed and also I tried to use p5.js for audio recording but I am getting issues in configuring it.

Please suggest me the best way to record audio in react(JavaScript) and to save it in my node server.

Answer (score 1):

The [react-mic](https://github.com/hackingbeauty/react-mic) project can handle the recording. Don't know how to do the server side; I'm still working on it myself.

Comment: Hey Trenton, did you achieve the server side functionality? I am stuck on the server side.

Comment: @SarfarazAhmed Did you implement react-mic in Next.js?

Comment: @Usman Later on i used mic-recorder-to-mp3 in my react js project. Not sure about Next js.